# Import local package from main in Go

Tags: go

I'm writing an API using Go and its `net/http` stdlib module and i have some utils code in a directory named utils. But when i import them in main, Go does not find the packages. The root cause is apparently the fact that Go packages have to be saved in `$GOPATH/src/`. So i wanted to know if there was a way to import local packages and save them in the same folder as the main package.

I'm following the Github Directory Structure so my $GOPATH looks like that.

```
$GOPATH/src/
   |___github.com/
       |___user/
           |___repository/
               |___main.go
               |___utils/
                   |___core.go
                   |___factory.go
```

As the utils directory is really tied to the app, it would be really bad for me to save it as a different Go app in $GOPATH/src. And apart from that, imagine the moment when i will want to push my code on Github. Here it's only 2 repositories but if it was 6 i would need 6 private repos for really related and tied parts of a single application.

Comment: how are you importing it?

Comment: `import "github.com/user/repository/utils/core"`. When i specify the package (here core), Go does not find it. And when i stop to utils, it says that there are 2 packages (core & factory)

Comment: Because there should be one directory per package

Comment: @phndiaye the `package` declaration on both files should be `package utils` and they should be imported with `import "github.com/user/repository/utils"`

Comment: Oh i see ! That was the issue. I declared both core & factory as utils package member and it works.

Comment: By the way, is there a way to import only one file (for example, only factory) and use it as prefix before the function to call. Currently i import `utils` and use `utils.MyPublicFunction()` wherever MyPublicFunction() is declared (factory or core) so it's hard to know to which "file" it belongs to. I wanted to use `factory.MyPublicFunction() instead...

Comment: @phndiaye nope, a package is a folder, and that's it - and all files in it must declare that folder name in their `package` declaration. If you want extra separation you can put your code in separate folders.

Comment: Well. Thanks for the answers. It helped a lot (for the case and also to learn more on Go) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Documenting an answer as it looks unanswered at first glance)

The `package` declaration on both files should be `package utils` and they should be imported with:

```
import "github.com/user/repository/utils"
```

Its also possible to make sub-packages (standard library `io` package has `io/ioutil`) if you really want to separate each code file as separate packages.

```
import "github.com/user/repository/utils"
import "github.com/user/repository/utils/sub"
```

The local directory structure would be:

```
$GOPATH/src/
   |___github.com/
       |___user/
           |___repository/
               |___main.go
               |___utils/
                   |___core.go
                   |___sub/factory.go
```

(Answer details posted in comment by @phndiaye)